# Desgined My Own PHP Framework.....How can I make it open source and let others build off it?

Tags: php, frameworks, open-source

So I designed my own custom PHP framework that as of right now is about 10 fold faster then YII. Obviously it has no where near the amounts of bells and whistle as YII, but it is a very fast MVC framework that only relies on the database for user content storage and nothing else. I have no idea where to post my code so others can play around with it and contribute.

Comment: https://www.github.com

Comment: The license is important. Use MIT/X11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for Sourceforge, it's a great open source community/repository.
Sourceforge - http://sourceforge.net/